# I don't know why categories are showing below post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a function which shows categories list. When I call it above the entry-header, It is also shown below content even I haven't call it there.

Also, the categories get duplicated e.g Our news category is shown three time.

My code looks like.

```
 if (!function_exists('category_renown')) :
    function category_renown() {
        $categories = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ' ', 'openblogger' ));
        if ( $categories ) {
                printf( '<span class="catu-links">' . esc_html__( '%1$s', 'openblogger' ) . '</span>', $categories ); // WPCS: XSS OK.
            }
    }
endif;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I guess you have wrapped function with wrong curly brace position.

Comment: The syntax is correct

Answer (score 0):

While testing your code here works fine. The problem seems not in the above code. You might need to check other code. Or provide here code that you've doubt about.